# appengine unit test fetches only 10 entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unit-testing, junit, objectify

I have written an Unit test with appengine where it needs to fetch 250 entities after populating 1000. However I see most of the time it only fetches only 10 entities. Only very few times I have seen it has fetched 250 of them. I am pretty sure that the temporary datastore does have 1000 entities because I am printing them while saving.

in @Before method

```
System.out.println( "Adding "+players.size()+ "  entries" );
ofy().save().entities(players);
```

prints 1000 as expected

in @Test method

```
List<Player> players = ofy().load().type( Player.class ).order("-score").limit( 250 ).list();
System.out.println( "Fetched "+players.size()+" top players" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it solved. As @pgiecek said earlier, its due to eventual consistency. I just had to modify the following code pupulating the records to be committed immediately.I went back to Master/slave mode

```
ofy().save().entities(rankings).now()
```

Comment: Calling now() forces synchronous completion of the operation; it has nothing to do with eventual consistency, the HRD, or M/S. This is most likely your problem - you have not demarcated your request boundaries, so all you're doing is adding pending futures to a single session.

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to the fact that the test datastore service simulates eventual consistency behaviour. Check your unapplied job percentage configuration.

> By setting the unapplied job percentage to 100, we are instructing the local datastore to operate with the maximum amount of eventual consistency. Maximum eventual consistency means writes will commit but always fail to apply, so global (non-ancestor) queries will consistently fail to see changes. This is of course not representative of the amount of eventual consistency your application will see when running in production, but for testing purposes, it's very useful to be able to configure the local datastore to behave this way every time.

Try something like this if it helps.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    localServiceTestHelper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
            new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(0));
}
```

However, be aware of the below fact.

> Note that `setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(0)` will switch local datastore service to Master/slave mode.

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests).

Comment: You may be right , when I pause the execution in debug mode , it fetches 250 but with the value 100 , its fetching 0 top players .and with value 0 its fetching 10.

Comment: If it helped you to solve your problem, mark the answer as accepted so that the others with the similar issue can benefit.

Comment: The problem isn't solved yet. The transaction is not failing with setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100), its just gives me 0 entities.

Comment: What transaction? It can return 0 entities since you use eventually consistent query. See the explanation above.

Comment: Anyway found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

While you may also be troubled by issues of eventual consistency, it's also likely that you are not demarcating your requests correctly. This will have two effects: You'll get session contamination, and pending asynchronous operations will not be committed.

Like JPA and JDO, Objectify is based on the idea of a session-of-work. In normal operation, this session of work is started and closed by the ObjectifyFilter; you get one session per request, and at the end of the session all pending async & deferred operations are flushed to the datastore.

In unit tests, there is no ObjectifyFilter and no implied notion of a request. For example, any individual test could make multiple requests! This is especially common if you are testing JAX-RS methods directly; each method is a separate request.

Thus, it's up to you to establish this context. In Objectify 5.1 and later, you must explicitly start a context. The best way is this:

```
ObjectifyService.run(new VoidWork() {
    public void vrun() {
        // the code you want to execute within a single request
    }
});
```

You might call this multiple times within a test to simulate multiple requests.

If, on the other hand, you are writing tests with the idea that each test executes fully within the context of a single request, you can set up and tear down that context in @Before/@After methods (or @BeforeMethod/@AfterMethod if using TestNG). See the static method `ObjectifyService.begin()`.

These are not mutually exclusive options; you can perform a `run()` operation even while a prior context exists; Objectify contexts work like a stack.

Comment: Instead of using `VoidWork`, I found it much simpler to start the unit test with `Closeable ofy = ObjectifyService.begin()` and after each asynchronous save, close the ofy service and open a new one through `ofy.close(); ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();`